# How to interpret memory profiler log in python to detect memory leak

Tags: python, sqlite, memory-leaks

I am trying to find a possible memory leak in my python script. I am using memory profiler but I am not sure how to interpret the memory profile output to detect the memory leak.

```
Filename: vc_query.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
   818    79.36 MiB    79.36 MiB           1       @profile(stream=open("mem_profile.log", "w"), precision=2)
   819                                             def run_query_n(args):
   820    79.36 MiB     0.00 MiB           1           def download_notifs(url, start, size, update):
   821                                                     payload.update({"start": start, "length": size})
   822                                                     partial = download_report(url=url, payload=payload, silent=True, client=vc_, method='POST', repeat=args.max_retry, repeat_after=1).json().get('data')
   823                                                     if partial:
   824                                                         for ea in partial:
   825                                                             ea.update(update)
   826                                                         outputs.extend(partial)
   827                                         
   828    79.38 MiB     0.02 MiB           5           started_range = list(map(lambda x: parser.parse(x), args.notif_between.split('->')))
   829    79.38 MiB     0.00 MiB           1           ranges = split_date(started_range[0], started_range[1], 'd')
   865    79.45 MiB     0.07 MiB           1           db, outputs = sqlite3.connect(":memory:"), []
   866   292.77 MiB     0.00 MiB           2           for dates in ranges:
   880    81.61 MiB     0.55 MiB           3                           roof = download_report(url=f"{base_url}reports/notifications2.json?status={statuses.index(status)}&{cat}{query}&report_type[]={n_type}", silent=True, client=vc_
   881    81.61 MiB     1.60 MiB           2                                                , method='POST', payload=payload).json().get('recordsFiltered')
   882    81.61 MiB     0.00 MiB           1                           if is_number(roof):
   883   292.77 MiB   211.08 MiB           2                               with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
   884    81.70 MiB     0.00 MiB           2                                   for i in range((int(roof) // int(args.page_size))+1):
   885    81.70 MiB     0.08 MiB           2                                       executor.submit(download_notifs, f"{base_url}reports/notifications2.json?status={statuses.index(status)}&{cat}{query}&report_type[]={n_type}"
   886    81.62 MiB     0.00 MiB           1                                                       , i*int(args.page_size), int(args.page_size), {'report_type': n_type})
   887   292.77 MiB     0.00 MiB           1           tse = datetime.now()
   888   292.77 MiB     0.00 MiB           1           if args.output:
   889   292.77 MiB     0.00 MiB           1               if 'return' not in args.output:
   890   292.77 MiB     0.00 MiB           1                   print(f'completed\tduration: {(tse - tss).seconds} seconds')
   891   292.77 MiB     0.00 MiB           1           sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS notif ("
   892   292.77 MiB     0.00 MiB          22           for field in notif_headers:
   893   292.77 MiB     0.00 MiB          21               sql = sql + field + " TEXT,"
   894   292.77 MiB     0.00 MiB           1           sql = sql[:-1] + ")"
   895   293.40 MiB     0.63 MiB           1           db.cursor().execute(sql)
   896   293.40 MiB     0.00 MiB           1           unique_id = set()
   897   293.40 MiB     0.00 MiB           1           if len(outputs) > 0:
   898   305.77 MiB     0.00 MiB       28639               for row in outputs:
   899   305.77 MiB     0.00 MiB       28638                   if row.get('id') in unique_id:
   900                                                             continue
   901   305.77 MiB     2.66 MiB       28638                   unique_id.add(row.get('id'))
   902   305.77 MiB     0.00 MiB       28638                   sql = "Insert INTO notif VALUES ("
   903   305.77 MiB     0.00 MiB      630036                   for key in notif_keys:
   904   305.77 MiB     0.00 MiB      601398                       try:
   905   305.77 MiB     0.00 MiB      601398                           value = get_json_value(row, key)
   906                                                             except Exception:
   907                                                                 value = ''
   908   305.77 MiB     0.02 MiB      601398                       sql = sql + "\"" + str(value).replace("\"", '') + "\","
   909   305.77 MiB     0.00 MiB       28638                   sql = sql[:-1] + ")"
   910   305.77 MiB     9.68 MiB       28638                   db.cursor().execute(sql)
   911   186.11 MiB  -119.66 MiB           1           outputs = []
   912   186.11 MiB     0.00 MiB           1           split_categories = set()
   913   186.11 MiB     0.00 MiB           1           db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
   914   187.64 MiB     1.53 MiB           1           query = db.cursor().execute(f"select * from notif" if args.sql == '' else args.sql).fetchall()
   915   187.64 MiB     0.00 MiB           1           found = 0
   916   187.64 MiB     0.00 MiB           1           limit = args.limit if args.limit else -1
   917   203.81 MiB -12335.21 MiB       28639           for r in query:
   918   203.81 MiB -12324.48 MiB       28638               if found == limit:
   919                                                         break
   920   203.81 MiB -12324.48 MiB       28638               dt = dict(r)
   927   203.81 MiB -12324.48 MiB       28638               found += 1
   928   203.81 MiB -12319.86 MiB       28638               dt.update(to_timestamp(dt))
   929   203.81 MiB -12335.22 MiB       28638               ot = {}
   930   203.81 MiB -12335.22 MiB       28638               if '@ALL' not in args.columns:
   931                                                         ot.update({key: val for key, val in dt.items() if key in args.columns})
   932                                                     else:
   933   203.81 MiB -12335.22 MiB       28638                   ot = dt.copy()
   934   203.81 MiB -12334.39 MiB       28638               outputs.append(ot)
   935   203.81 MiB -12335.21 MiB       28638               if hasattr(args, 'split'):
   936                                                         split_categories.add(ot.get(args.split[0]))
   937   183.94 MiB   -19.87 MiB           1           db.close()
   938   183.95 MiB     0.00 MiB           1           return outputs
```

I expect the memory usage return to where it began at line 820 and since I run this as a service (it is an infinite loop) the memory usage keeps growing.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the leak is from the list variable "partial" that gets created inside download_notifs().